# How to create custom attributes in azure ad B2C tenant which are unique

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I defined a custom attribute (CompanyName - string) which identifies a company uniquely. There will be only 1 user per company. 
Currently I am struggling to find a way to mark this attribute as unique. 
Is it supported ?
Or do i need to do something else ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't declare a custom attribute as unique so you must validate the attribute value, when it is entered by a new user, using [a custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom) that invokes [a REST API that validates the user input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-validation-custom).

The REST API can query whether the attribute value already exists using [an Azure AD Graph API request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions#FilterAnExtensionValue) such as:

`https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?$filter=extension_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_CompanyName eq 'Contoso'`